# Ngrok Docker container fails to start giving a version error

Tags: docker, ngrok

In Ngrok docker, using compose, there's a constant error saying:

ngrok.yml

```yaml
verion: "3" 
authtoken: "<your-auth-token-1>" 
tunnels: 
  webapp: 
    proto: http 
    hostname: usable-honeybee-workable.ngrok-free.app 
    addr: webapp-1:8080 
    inspect: false 
    host_header: rewrite 
    bind_tls: true 
    labels: 
      - env=dev 
      - team=infra
```

docker-compose.yaml

```yaml
version: '3.1'

services:
  webapp:
    image: mywebapp
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
  ngrok:                                                                           
    image: ngrok/ngrok:alpine                                                      
    restart: unless-stopped                                                        
    environment:                                 
      NGROK_AUTHTOKEN: <your-auth-token-1>
    command:                                                            
      - "start"                                                         
      - "--all"                                                         
      - "--config"                                                      
      - "/etc/ngrok.yml"                                                
    volumes:                                                            
      - ./ngrok/ngrok.yml:/etc/ngrok.yml                                
    ports:                                                              
      - 4040:4040
```

Starting the containers

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml up -d
```

docker ps show the ngrok container being restarted continuously:

```
2b2e2922b797   ngrok/ngrok:alpine   "/nix/store/m068srsx…"   12 minutes ago   Restarting (1) 4 seconds ago
```

Upon checking logs using:

```bash
docker logs <container-id> --follow | more
```

I see:

```
ERROR:  Error reading configuration file '/etc/ngrok.yml': `version` property is required.
ERROR:  
ERROR:  If you're upgrading from an older version of ngrok, you can run:
ERROR:  
ERROR:      ngrok config upgrade
ERROR:  
ERROR:  to upgrade to the new format and add the version number.
```

Has anyone come across this issue? I added the version tag into the ngrok.yaml as you can see, tried with "2" and "3" with no luck.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PM from ngrok here. The short answer here is that the version in your config should be 2.

The long answer is that the version of the ngrok binary and the version of the syntax of the config file can and have been rev'd independently. We wanted to leave the option open to make breaking changes to the syntax of the config file without needing to make breaking changes to the agent.

Comment: Thank you, Russ. I tried with version 2 as well, is there anything else I should look into?

Comment: Double checking that in the ngrok.yaml file, you haven't misspelled `version`? I see `verion: "3" ` in your original post.

Comment: Oh indeed. that could be the issue. Let me check. Thank you.